# How to properly return a value from a callback within a Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, electron

I know that very similar questions have been asked, but I can't find one that fits my issue exactly- feel free to point me that way if there is one.

```
sendSteamAuthTicket: () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        greenworks.getAuthSessionTicket(function(ticket) {
            console.log('Successfully retrieved Steam API User Auth Ticket.')
            console.log(ticket.ticket.toString('hex'))
            resolve(ticket.ticket.toString('hex'))
        }, function(e) { throw e })
    })
}
```

Basically, this returns an endlessly pending Promise, leading me to believe I can't resolve a Promise from within a nested callback like this. Unfortunately, I can't send the data via an additional function because electron won't let you interface with the browser that way.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do here? e.g. more or less obtain a delayed Promise value within this single function?

Comment: Why is it forever pending? Does `getAuthSessionTicket` not call the callback?

Comment: You may need to await the API call if it is async?

Comment: You should use `reject(e)` instead of `throw e` (which nothing can catch).

Comment: callback has nothing to do with Promise. if `resolve` is called, it'll be fulfilled. if it's not being fulfilled it's because `resolve` is not called.

Comment: Do you see the log messages?

Comment: Let me double check that it's calling the function normally (regardless of the return value), will edit in a moment with results

Also, I don't see the log messages, no. It's part of why I'm confused? Am I using this function incorrectly? (it will log correctly outside of being used in a promise like so)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I figured it out- sorry for the redundant question, I've been banging my head on this for a few hours. Hearing that the Promise syntax was correct was apparently enough to get it through.

The greenworks package was being imported incorrectly (or, rather, correctly- according to their docs- but needed a direct file path)

It's a little outdated so I wasn't sure why at first.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the way that you're calling `resolve`. If the callback is called, `resolve` will be, too, unless `ticket` is null or similar. My guess would be that greenworks is calling the error callback and then not re-throwing your thrown error. Try doing `reject(e)` instead of `throw e`.